# Net Core 6 Web API - Multiple Bearer validators, prevent error log spam

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication

I have a .NET Core 6 Web API and I use multiple Bearers and multiple authentication Schemes.

This question is a good example of it
[How add two different tokens in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57299568/how-add-two-different-tokens-in-asp-net-core-web-api)
However, Once one token arrives, it is validated through both validators, which results in my logs being spammed with "fake" errors because of course one validator can't validate a token from a different issuer. How can I avoid the unnecessary logging of said errors? Or make it so the validator won't even attempt to validate a token that doesn't match its valid issuers?